# Executing a .bat script when starting a windows docker container

Tags: windows, visual-studio, docker, batch-file, cmd

I'm setting up a windows container running a windows image with visual studio 2019 build tools. To set up correctly, I need to run the .bat file **"vcvarsall.bat"** that is inside the container (located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build`) whenever we start up the container.

This allows me to compile projects using cl and link from the command line. Here's my current Dockerfile :

```
FROM abrarov/msvc-2019

COPY eigen\ C:\\Users\\ContainerUser\\Documents\\libraries;

RUN setx path "%path%;c:\cmake\bin";
RUN setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build";
ENTRYPOINT vcvarsall.bat x86_x64
```

This executes the script whenever I run the container with `docker run --rm -ti myContainer`, but terminates the container as soon as it ends executing the script. As far as I understand, this is normal behavior of ENTRYPOINT, but I want to stay inside the container and be able to interact with it. How can I work around this? Is there a way to launch a new cmd.exe so that the process doesn't end until the user types `exit`?

Comment: I don't know anything about docker but this might work if you want cmd.exe to stay open. `ENTRYPOINT cmd.exe /K "CALL vcvarsall.bat x86_x64"`

Comment: @Squashman it worked, thank you so much. Could you explain to me what the /K and CALL commands are for?

Comment: From the help file for `CMD.exe` **/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains**.  I am not sure if you need `CALL` or not.  Normally if you execute a batch file from another batch file you need to use `CALL` so that control returns to the parent process.  If you do not use `CALL` then control is passed to the batch file that was called which may then terminate your session once the called batch file exits.